# ActionBarDrawerToggle error in Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am newbie to Android and I am trying to create a navigation drawer following a tutorial. Everything seems fine until I got stuck to this part. The error has something to do with the actionbardrawertoggle. I put an indication where the error is. please help me.

[image]

[image]

```
private DrawerLayout drawerlayout;
private ListView listView;
private String[] sample;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerListener;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_phrismdashboard);

    sample=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sample);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sample));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    drawerlayout=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
   ERROR HERE------> drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerlayout, R.drawable.drawer_shadow, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            Toast.makeText(PHRISMDashboard.this, "On drawer opened", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            Toast.makeText(PHRISMDashboard.this, "On drawer closed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    drawerlayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
 drawerlayout,
 R.drawable.drawer_shadow, <== delete this argument
 R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
 R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
```

Remove  R.drawable.drawer_shadow, and replce with your toolbar.
I think there is the problem.

There are two ActionBarDrawerToggle classes.
you should go through these:
[support.v4's](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) and
[support.v7's](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) .

You may fix it simply by removing the third argument drawerImageRes.

```
drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
 drawerlayout,
 R.drawable.drawer_shadow, <== delete this argument 
 R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
 R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
```

Comment: drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
 drawerlayout,
 R.drawable.ic_drawer, <---- nav drawer image
 R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
 R.string.navigation_drawer_close)

Comment: the R.drawable.drawer_shadow is the nav drawer image. What toolbar are you pertaining sir?

Comment: See above i have made changes
you should delete  R.drawable.drawer_shadow

Comment: I tried to delete it however theres an error too. Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: can i see your imports ?
did you import

 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

Comment: these are my imports sir `import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
`

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is replace toolbar by other instance.
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

```
drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(Context,DrawerLayout,
Toolbar,
String,
String)
```